# How to compare or find common properties of unitary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

I have multiple $3\times 3$ unitary matrices, all of which optimize a function $f$. I want to find the structure or common pattern/properties of these unitaries.

The function $f$ to be optimized has 9 parameters(real numbers). These 9 parameters are used to generate a $3\times 3$ unitary matrix, and then use it to maximize a function.
The function works like:

1. Generate a unitary matrix $U$ from the 9 input parameters.
2. M = I $ \otimes $ I $ \otimes $ U, where is $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix
3. E = MQ, where $M$ is a $27 \times 27$ matrix and $Q$ is $27 \times 1$ matrix
4. Reshape $E$ to be of size $3 \times 9$
5. Compute SVD of $E$ and let $s_1,s_2,s_3$ be the singular values of E.
6. Maximise $-\sum_{x_i} p(x_i)\  log \ p(x_i)$, where $x = \{s_1^2, s_2^2, s_3^2\}$

I have found the parameters that maximize this function. The parameters are not unique. Hence, I have many different unitary matrices, all of which maximise $f$. And I don't know if there is anything common about these unitaries.

So far I have tried comparing their eigenvalues, eigenvectors, trace, determinant and inverse. But none of these values are equal.

What other ways can I try to find the common structure of these unitaries?

Comment: Is it possible to explain how the matrices are being generated with words and math instead of code?

Comment: Yes. The unitary matrix is generated by taking the matrix exponential of a self-adjoint matrix. The diagonal elements of the self-adjoint matrix are real.

Comment: The matrix exponential of a self-adjoint matrix is not unitary. Perhaps you mean the matrix exponential of $i$ times a self-adjoint matrix? But the matrix exponential of one matrix is one matrix, so how are you getting multiple unitary matrices?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. Its the matrix exponential of  times a self-adjoint matrix. The multiple unitary matrices part is like this: I have a function to optimize. The parameters of this function are the 9 parameters that generate a unitary, which is then used to compute the function. The optimum parameters for the function do not come out to be unique. The multiple unitaries are the result of these multiple optimum parameters.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You are asking what do matrices that are exponentials of $i$ times self-adjoint matrices have in common? If so, the answer is: they are unitary. There is nothing else they have in common (all unitary matrices are of this form, this follows from the spectral theorem).

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the $9$ parameters to generate unitary matrices as linear combinations of some obvious choice of basis for the self-adjoint matrices. It will be hard, maybe impossible, to answer your question without knowing what the unitary matrices are and what the function is that they optimize. If the function itself has some symmetry, then the set of unitary matrices which optimize it will also have some symmetry, even if their features aren't "equal." If the function has no symmetry, then this may just be a raw algebra/calc problem with no magical solution,

Comment: @tomasz I have many unitary matrices that optimise a function, and want to know what do these matrices have in common.  I have updated the question.  Hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: @runway44 I have added the function they are optimizing. May I know what specifically you mean by symmetry in this case? Do you mean the matrix will be symmetric?

Comment: No, I mean the *set* of the optimal unitary matrices will have some kind of symmetry if the objective function does. At the moment, what's still unclear is what we know about $Q$ (and technically, the exact way $E$ is reshaped).